# Reverse Age Calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need some help and I hope you guys can help me.

I'm trying to figure out how to Calculate what the "**Date**" will be when a person will turn "**100 Years**"

In my current code I'm able to calculate "**Person Age**" from "**Date Input**"

Please help me figure this out how to calculate "**Date**" from "**User Age Input**".

Thanks in advance

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exer_13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* ------------------------------------------ */
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            String name = "";
            DateTime birthDate;

            /* ------------------------------------------ */
            Console.WriteLine("Current Date Is: " + dt);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\r");

            Console.Write("Please Enter Your Name: ");
            name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("\n\r");

            Console.Write("Enter your birtdate (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
            if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out birthDate))
            {
                TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - birthDate;
                Console.WriteLine("Your Name Is: " + name + " And Your age Is: {0} years and {1} days", (int)(age.Days / 365.25), age.Days % 365.25);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\r");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date." + Environment.NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\r");
            }


            /*
               Code goes here
            */
            Console.WriteLine("You will be 100 Years old At this Date: ");


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: What problem did you encounter calculating this?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add years to their date of birth.

```
var oneHundredth = birthDate.AddYears(100);
```

Comment: Where is this to be added ?

Comment: After you get the input from the use

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as, this will ask the number of year after you want to get the date

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exer_13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        /* ------------------------------------------ */
       DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String name = "";
        DateTime birthDate;
        DateTime futureDay;
        int age;

        /* ------------------------------------------ */
        Console.WriteLine("Current Date Is: " + dt);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r");

        Console.Write("Please Enter Your Name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r");

        Console.Write("Enter your birthday: ");
        if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out birthDate))
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("You will be 100 Years old At this Date: {0}", birthDate);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\r");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid year." + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\r");
        }

        Console.Write("Enter age: ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
        {
            //TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - birthDate;
            futureDay = birthDate.AddYears(age);
            Console.WriteLine("You will be 100 Years old At this Date: {0}", futureDay.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine("\n\r");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid year." + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\r");
        }


        /*
           Code goes here
        */


        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think that your code it is giving correct output.

Like If I'm 30 years now at 2016 - then it says that date is "2051-05-15" at age 35

Comment: ok got it what do you want you want date from the birth day ? I am editing my answer

Comment: Simply I need to display the date at selected age

So if born at 06/17/1985 - Current age is 30

What is the date at 100 years old

Comment: see my update, this time it prompt user to input `name`, `birthday` and age after that it will calculate the date after that age

Comment: Thanks

Works great now

Comment: One last thing - is it possible to output as day

Comment: means without time ?

Comment: Yeah like with day of the week

Comment: ok see my update, I have edit here `Console.WriteLine("You will be 100 Years old At this Date: {0}", futureDay.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));`

Comment: If you dont mind - Is there a way to calculate when user next birthday is

Im still new in Programming